# Erro em struct linguagem C

Tags: c, struct, debug

Galera, tô fazendo uma código que a primeiro momento deve armazenar o cadastro de pacientes de uma clínica, pra isso tô usando struct e uma variável desse struct para armazenar dados para 5 pacientes. O problema é que, na execução do programa, quando chega no 5º paciente a exibição de dados foge do previsto e o código simplesmente fecha quando insiro o endereço do paciente. Isso ocorre quando compilo pelo Visual Code, no GDB Online funciona normalmente. Em nenhum dos casos é indicado algum erro e não consegui achar a razão. Alguém me da uma luz?

//bibliotecas: #include <stdio.h>    #include <locale.h>

//structs

```
struct PACIENTE {
    int codPaciente;
    char nome[50];
    char endereco[100];
    char telefone[14];
};
```

//funções secundárias

```
//cadastro de pacientes 
void paciente () {

    //declaração de variáveis
    struct PACIENTE pacientes[4] = { 0 };
    int validacao;

    //processamento de dados
    for (int i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++) {

        printf("Insira o código do paciente %d: ", i + 1);
        scanf("%i", &pacientes[i].codPaciente);
        setbuf(stdin, NULL);

            if (i > 0) {
                
                do {
                    validacao = 0;

                    for (int j = 0 ; j < i ; j++) {
                        
                        if (pacientes[i].codPaciente == pacientes[j].codPaciente)
                            validacao = 1;
                    }

                    if (validacao == 1) {
                        printf("    Código repetido. Insira outro código para o paciente %d: ", i + 1);
                        scanf("%i", &pacientes[i].codPaciente);
                        setbuf(stdin, NULL);
                    }

                } while (validacao == 1);
            }

        printf("Insira o nome do paciente %d: ", i + 1);
        fgets(pacientes[i].nome, sizeof(pacientes[i].nome), stdin);
        setbuf(stdin, NULL);

        printf("Insira o endereço do paciente %d: ", i + 1);
        fgets(pacientes[i].endereco, sizeof(pacientes[i].endereco), stdin);
        setbuf(stdin, NULL);

        printf("Insira o telefone do paciente %d: ", i + 1);
        fgets(pacientes[i].telefone, sizeof(pacientes[i].telefone), stdin);
        setbuf(stdin, NULL);

        printf("%s\n", pacientes[i].telefone);
    }
}
```

//programa principal

int main () {

```
//definição para idioma
setlocale(LC_ALL,"Portuguese");

//input de dados 
printf("\nBem vindo :) \n\n");

//processamento de dados 
paciente();

printf("\n\n\nFim do programa.\n\n\n");
return 0;  //finalizar o programa
```

}

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Caro gufdoor, primeiramente queria te desejar uma boa noite!
Em segundo lugar queria ressaltar a importância de sua pergunta para a nossa comunidade, tenho certeza que muitos profissionais experientes cometeriam esse erro e sei que essa sua postagem vai ser de grande utilidade para todos os tipos de programadores.

-----resolvendo----

O problema é que `struct PACIENTE pacientes[4] = { 0 };`, você foi infeliz ao declarar um vetor com 4 posições na intensão de utilizar 5. Mas devo enfatizar seu código que tinha várias funções muito interessantes e diferentes. Parabéns! Seja muito feliz com seus pacientes, médicos e consultas, até um outro dia, um forte abraço!  ❤️